# Unexpected return value in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variable-assignment

```
def gen_path_locations(start, destination)
    initial_dest = destination
    last_dest = destination
    path_locations = []
    loop do
        last_dest[0] -= 1 if initial_dest[0] > start[0]
        last_dest[0] += 1 if initial_dest[0] < start[0]
        last_dest[1] -= 1 if initial_dest[1] > start[0]
        last_dest[1] += 1 if initial_dest[1] < start[0]
        break if last_dest == start
        path_locations << last_dest
        puts last_dest.inspect
    end
    path_locations
end
```

`gen_path_locations([5, 5], [9, 9])` returns `[[5, 5], [5, 5], [5, 5]]`

It adds the starting location to my path_locations instead of the current iteration of last_dest. Of course, if I change the push over to this:

```
path_locations << [last_dest[0], last_dest[1]]
```

It returns the expected values. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

A `.clone`:

```
path_locations << last_dest.clone
```

Otherwise, you keep adding the same object whose contents you keep changing; in the end, you will still have the same object three times, whose contents are whatever you changed it to last.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
a = ["foo", "bar"]
b = [a, a, a]
# => [["foo", "bar"], ["foo", "bar"], ["foo", "bar"]]
a[1] = "quux"
b
# => [["foo", "quux"], ["foo", "quux"], ["foo", "quux"]]
```

You can see what is happening [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B%22foo%22,+%22bar%22%5D%0Ab+%3D+%5Ba,+a,+a%5D%0Aa%5B1%5D+%3D+%22quux%22%0Aprint(b)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=4). The tool is not for Ruby, but happily the example works in Python as well.

**EDIT**: Actually, [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+gen_path_locations(start,+destination)%3A%0A++++initial_dest+%3D+destination%0A++++last_dest+%3D+destination%0A++++path_locations+%3D+%5B%5D%0A++++while+True%3A%0A++++++++if+initial_dest%5B0%5D+%3E+start%5B0%5D%3A%0A++++++++++++last_dest%5B0%5D+-%3D+1%0A++++++++if+initial_dest%5B0%5D+%3C+start%5B0%5D%3A%0A++++++++++++last_dest%5B0%5D+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++if+initial_dest%5B1%5D+%3E+start%5B0%5D%3A%0A++++++++++++last_dest%5B1%5D+-%3D+1%0A++++++++if+initial_dest%5B1%5D+%3C+start%5B0%5D%3A%0A++++++++++++last_dest%5B1%5D+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++if+last_dest+%3D%3D+start%3A%0A++++++++++++return+path_locations%0A++++++++path_locations.append(last_dest)%0Agen_path_locations(%5B5,+5%5D,+%5B9,+9%5D)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) is the link to visualisation of *your* code, rewritten into Python - you can step through and see exactly what is happening. Then replace the append line with `path_locations.append([last_dest[0], last_dest[1]])`, which is exactly what you did (and exactly what Ruby's `clone` does more succintly), and see how it changes the program.